Why do all windows move to main display after a lock screen or sleep?
Trying to figure out why after a sleep or screen lock, when my system is awakened all open windows are moved to the main display. Both displays are Apple Thunderbolt 27" Displays and both are set to 2560x1440 default.
Mac Studio specs:

macOS Sonoma 14.5
Chip is Apple M1 Max

Found nothing in settings for a lock screen:

Energy Saver Settings:

Window settings & Mission Control:

Desktop & Stage Manager:

No updates are reported to be needed and my computer is current. How can I stop all windows from moving to the main display when waking and logging in?
